# Distroying session in php set by jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, session

How can I destroy a session in php which set by jquery.

The code to register the session is:

```
$('#psubmit').click(function() {  

    $.post("single-us_portfolio.php", {"myusername": "myusername"});    

});
```

and to access session on custom.php the code is:

```
    session_start();
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $_POST["myusername"];
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){

echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url=http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/the-lexicon/">';
}
```

Now I want to destroy this session on the this form submission:

```
<form >
<input type="file" class="js-file-validation-image" name="file" id="filed"   required="required">
<input type="submit" value="PUBLISH PHOTO" id="hello" name="publishpost" >
</form>
```

Comment: When u want to destroy session? on which event?

Comment: on the click of submit button with id "hello" in last form

Comment: you can just use `session_destroy` function when you want.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you want to destroy session include following  code

Say this is in session_destroy.php file

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();//OR use unset if u want to destroy individual session.
clearstatcache();
?>
```

And give ajax call to this file,on any event u want.

For ajax call

```
jQuery("#psubmit").mousedown(function(){

 hasBeenClicked = 1;                            
 //AJAX call
  $.ajax({
        url: 'session_destroy.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {

        },
        success: function(data){                                

        }
    });
 ////AJAX call

  });
```

Comment: How? ajax call to this file? please

Comment: This is how u give ajax call to destroy session

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are maintained on server and could not removed on client without sending request to server. so you should provide another api for the latter form to destroy session server side just like setting session server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy the session on the jQuery post like so:

```
$('#hello').click(function() {  

    $.post("destroy.php", function(){  
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Then in destroy.php

```
sessionstart();
sessiondestroy();
```

If you are using it on a form you have to make sure that you have prevented the default form submission if you want it to make the ajax call without reloading.